# HTML5 Websockets

Tags: html, websocket

I'm evaluating PusherApp, and I'm trying to figure out how the events work. Haven't found any samples in .NET using Pusher but if I say:

```
var socket = new Pusher(...)

socket.bind("onmessagecomplete", function(message){
   //-- do something in here...
})
```

For this to kick off, is this a javascript event I need to trigger somehow? I would be doing some sort of server side work at the time then I'll need to trigger this event but not sure how from the server? I'm using C#. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No, that event is automatically fired when you receive a notification from Pusher and your callback function is run. It receives the notifications via the WebSocket you opened when you called `new Pusher()`.

On the server you use the [REST API](http://pusherapp.com/docs/rest_api) to send data to Pusher which it then pushes to the client and that javascript callback is fired.

Answer (score 0):

The `onmessagecomplete` event will be triggered from a server-side call to the REST API (as @andrew-marshall points out). You can trigger events from .NET using the [Pusher .NET REST library](https://github.com/grahamscott/pusherrestdotnet) which has been written in C#.

The reason this can clearly be identified as a server triggered event is that any client events must have a `client-` prefix.